# Using Jackson 2.2 to serialize Hibernate result into JSON string, infinite loop

Tags: json, hibernate, jackson, hibernate-criteria

I have a bi-directional relationship between 2 objects - EvalMasterEvaluation (one) and EvalMasterEvalDetail (many). I've tried a number of different solutions, but I must be implementing them wrong. My goal is to return a list of details for a given eval id.

I'm using Jackson 2.2 (with databind and datatype-hibernate3 libs), hibernate 3.6 and spring 3.2.1. Some code omitted to make this easier to read.

The parent class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class EvalMasterEvaluation implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigDecimal id;
    @JsonManagedReference private Set<EvalMasterEvalDetail> evalMasterEvalDetails = new HashSet<EvalMasterEvalDetail>(
            0);
}
```

The child class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class EvalMasterEvalDetail implements java.io.Serializable {
    private BigDecimal id;
    @JsonBackReference private EvalMasterEvaluation evalMasterEvaluation;
    private String active;
}
```

My Hibernate Criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EvalMasterEvalDetail.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("active", "Y"))
                    .setFetchMode("evalMasterEvaluation", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .createAlias("evalMasterEvaluation", "eval")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("eval.id", evalId))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("detailOrder"));

            details = criteria.list();

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(details);
```

EvalMasterEvaluation mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalMasterEvaluation" table="EVAL_MASTER_EVALUATION">
        <id name="id" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence-identity" >
                <param name="sequence">EVAL_MASTER_EVALUATION_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <set name="evalMasterEvalDetails" table="EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="MASTER_EVAL_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalMasterEvalDetail" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

EvalMasterEvalDetail mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalMasterEvalDetail" table="EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL">
        <id name="id" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence-identity" >
                <param name="sequence">EVAL_MASTER_EVAL_DETAIL_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="evalMasterEvaluation" class="org.anes.surveys.domain.EvalMasterEvaluation" fetch="select">
            <column name="MASTER_EVAL_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="active" type="string">
            <column name="ACTIVE" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AYE! After 2 days I finally found my mistake. I forgot to register the Hibernate3Module. My criteria/mapper code is now:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EvalMasterEvalDetail.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("active", "Y"))
                    .setFetchMode("evalMasterEvaluation", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .createAlias("evalMasterEvaluation", "eval")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("eval.id", evalId))
                    .addOrder(Order.asc("detailOrder"));

            details = criteria.list();

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate3Module());
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(details);
```

evalMasterEvaluation values are missing, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Did you find your solution for the values as well?

Comment: I've since scrapped this query. I don't remember now if I fixed it, but the Hibernate 3 Module works successfully with other hql queries in my app.